# Bluetooth Devices Not Detected with Bluetooth Scan

Tags: android, bluetooth, device, scanning

I've made a little android app to scan for Bluetooth devices and send an HTTP request to my server so i can detect if they are on or off. I've tested it with my Desktop PC with a Bluetooth Adapter and it works just fine. It shows pc is on when detected and off when i turn off bluetooth on PC. Now, the devices that I'd need to use this app for are: a Yaber Projector, Bose SoundLink and JBL Headset, but I'm encountering some problems with these.

First, the Projector seems not being able to comunicate with phones, I can connect only Headset or Speakers going into the projector BT settings and scanning for devices, but when I'm scanning to find my phone nothing appears, like the projector were invisivble to phone, resulting in the app detecting it always off. Same thing if i scan for the projector with my phone. How is that possible?

And last the speakers and headsets, it seems that once they are connected to a device (such as the projector) they are no longer visible to the phone, i think this has something to do with battery saving/security. But is there a workaround to keep being able to detect them even when they are connected?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is the code in the service to run the scan, as far as i understood it's using bluetooth classing technology not BLE.

```
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    createNotificationChannel();

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent1,0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"BTAPP")
            .setContentTitle("Bluetooth Scan")
            .setContentText("App is scanning")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(1,notification);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    IntentFilter intentFilter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    IntentFilter intentFilter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter2);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter3);
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    return START_STICKY;
}

final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery starts
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            //clearing any existing list data
            flagJBL = false;
            flagBose = false;
            flagProjector = false;
            arrayList.clear();
        }

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Add the name and address to an array adapter
            if (!arrayList.contains(device)) {
                if (device.getAddress().equals(JBL_HEADSET_ADDRESS))
                    flagJBL = true;
                if (device.getAddress().equals(BOSE_SOUNDLINK_ADDRESS))
                    flagBose = true;
                if (device.getAddress().equals(PROJECTOR_ADDRESS))
                    flagProjector = true;
                arrayList.add(device);
            }
        }

        // When discovery starts
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            //clearing any existing list data
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scan has stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (flagJBL) {
                Intent jbloni = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RequestHandler.class);
                jbloni.putExtra("URL",JBL_ON_URL);
                startService(jbloni);
            }
            //showNotification("JBL Result", "JBL is On");
            else {
                Intent jbloffi = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RequestHandler.class);
                jbloffi.putExtra("URL",JBL_OFF_URL);
                startService(jbloffi);
            }
            //showNotification("JBL Result", "JBL is Off");
            if (flagBose) {
                Intent boseoni = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RequestHandler.class);
                boseoni.putExtra("URL",BOSE_ON_URL);
                startService(boseoni);
                // showNotification("Bose Result", "Bose is On");
            }
            else {
                Intent boseoffi = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RequestHandler.class);
                boseoffi.putExtra("URL",BOSE_OFF_URL);
                startService(boseoffi);
                //showNotification("Bose Result", "Bose is Off");
            }
            if (flagProjector) {
                Intent projectoroni = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RequestHandler.class);
                projectoroni.putExtra("URL",PROJECTOR_ON_URL);
                startService(projectoroni);
                //showNotification("Projector Result", "Projector is On");
            }
            else {
                Intent projectoroffi = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RequestHandler.class);
                projectoroffi.putExtra("URL",PROJECTOR_OFF_URL);
                startService(projectoroffi);
                //showNotification("Projector Result", "Projector is Off");
            }

            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The speaker and headphones most likely allow only one bluetooth device as source of music at any given time. thats why they are hiding if you connect to them

Comment: Yeah that is what i tought, therefore the app will not be usable on them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description it sounds like that your Android app ist scanning for Bluetooth LE devices only. As the projector most likely uses Bluetooth classic and both technologies, except for their name, are incompatible your unable to scan for it. If you want to detect those devices too, you need to scan for Bluetooth classic devices in a second step.

As far as your speakers and headset are concerned, I can say from my observation that this behaviour is virtually industry standard. Even if it is technically possible to continue to advertise one's presence during a connection, from an application point of view it only makes sense in rare scenarios and is therefore only very rarely implemented.

Comment: I've added the code, but as i understood it's using classic BT not BLE. Could it be the opposite? The projector using BLE? Even if I think that would be unlikely.

Comment: I agree, according to your code you are doing a Bluetooth  classic discovery procedure. I had orientated myself on the wording and there 'scan' rather stands for Bluetooth LE, whereas in the context of Bluetooth classic 'discovery' is more common.
Regarding the receiver not being found - as also stated in the Android documentation a device needs to be 'discoverable' to be found in the discovery procedure. Maybe this needs to be enabled somehow.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()

Comment: But if i turn on my speaker it automatically connects to the projector, so it is discoverable, but i can't find it with the phone. May it be discoverable only for certain devices? Same thing if i do the opposite, scan for the phone in the projector BT settings, it scans speakers but not phone.

Comment: Your assumption that a Bluetooth device, which can be connected by another one, is 'discoverable' is wrong. If both connection partners 'know' each other (because they were already paired and bonded) the devices do not need to be 'discoverable'.

Comment: That the projector doesn't list a mobile phone is most likely a result of incompatibility.  The projector as an 'Audio Distribution Source' searches for 'Audio Distribution Sinks' like speakers and headsets and not for another 'source' device like a mobile phone ...

Comment: Got it. Thanks!